# Are you sure the following is true or not.:$(0.\overline{9}=1 )$

Tags: number-theory

Are you sure the following is true or not.:

$(0.\overline{9}=1 )$

If proven true or false is not.Thank

Comment: Are you asking whether $0.9999\overline{9}=1$? The slash usually indicates division, but I have a hard time believing you want to know if zero divided by something (nine?) is equal to one.

Comment: I've up-voted the question and voted to close it as a duplicate.  At least two people have down-voted it.  Perhaps an explanation of the reason for that could help. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't downvote (I rarely do), but the OP could have searched a bit better for the duplicate.